# Arduino elevator

Tags: arrays, arduino

I have started programming a three floor elevator with arduino. So far I could manage to call the lift from each floor and move the car toward the selected floor.For now I am trying to store pressed buttons in an array and move the elevator to the selected floors in the order of calls. However the car moves only to one floor and stop there and doesn't continues to the next selected floor. Here is what I have done.

```
const int maxfloors = 3;

byte carcall_buttons[maxfloors] = {22,24,46};
byte floor_sensors[maxfloors] = {25,26,47};

int buttonstate[3];
int sensorstate[3];

boolean registered[3] = {false, false, false};


int lastbuttonstate0 = LOW;
int lastbuttonstate1 = LOW;
int lastbuttonstate2 = LOW;

int lastsensorstate0 = LOW;
int lastsensorstate1 = LOW;
int lastsensorstate2 = LOW;

const byte led1 = 27;
const byte led2 = 23;
const byte led3 = 48;

const int motor_up = 41;
const int motor_down = 42;
const int  En = 40;

enum state {down,stop};
state elevator_state;


void setup()
{
  for (int i = 0; i<maxfloors; i++)
  {
    pinMode (carcall_buttons[i], INPUT);
    pinMode (floor_sensors[i], INPUT);
  }

  pinMode (led1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (led2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (led3, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(motor_up, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motor_down, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(En, OUTPUT);

  Serial.begin (9600);
}

void loop()
{

  ReadButtons();
  ReadSensors();
  FloorSelection();

  static int elevator_state = stop;

   switch (elevator_state)
  {
    case down:

    if (registered[0] == true || registered[1] == true)
    {
      if (sensorstate[2] == LOW)
      {
      movedown();
      elevator_state = stop;
      }
    }

    break;

    case stop:

    if (registered[1] == true && sensorstate[1] == LOW)
    {
      motor_stop();
      registered[1] = false;

      for (int i=0;i<maxfloors;i++)
      {
        Serial.println (registered[i]);
      }

    }

    if (registered[0] == true && sensorstate[0] == LOW)
    {
      motor_stop();
      registered[0] = false;

      for (int i=0;i<maxfloors;i++)
      {
        Serial.println (registered[i]);
      }
    }

    break;
  }
}



void ReadButtons()
{   

  for (int i=0;i<maxfloors;i++)
  {
    buttonstate[i] = digitalRead (carcall_buttons[i]);
  }
}

void ReadSensors()
{   

  for (int i=0;i<maxfloors;i++)
  {
    sensorstate[i] = digitalRead (floor_sensors[i]);
  }
}

void FloorSelection()
{

  for (int i=0;i<maxfloors;i++)
  {
  if (buttonstate[0] != lastbuttonstate0)
  {
    if (buttonstate[0] == HIGH)
    {
    registered [0] = true;

    delay(100);
    Serial.println (registered [i]);
    }
  }

  if (buttonstate[1] != lastbuttonstate1)
  {
    if (buttonstate[1] == HIGH)
    {
    registered [1] = true;

    delay(100);
   Serial.println (registered [i]);
    }
  }

  if (buttonstate[2] != lastbuttonstate2)
  {
    if (buttonstate[2] == HIGH)
    {
    registered [2] = true;

    delay(100);
   Serial.println (registered [i]);
    }
  }
}
}

void motor_stop()
{

  digitalWrite(led1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(led2, LOW);
  Serial.println ("idle");

  digitalWrite(motor_up, LOW);
  digitalWrite(motor_down, LOW);
  digitalWrite(En, LOW);
} 

 void moveup()
{
  digitalWrite(led1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(led2, LOW);
  Serial.println ("up");

  digitalWrite(motor_up, LOW);
  digitalWrite(motor_down, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(En, HIGH);
}


void movedown()
{
  digitalWrite(led1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(led2, HIGH);
  Serial.println ("down");

  digitalWrite(motor_up, LOW);
  digitalWrite(motor_down, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(En, HIGH);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your code correctly, you're not storing the selected floors into "an array in the order of the call".

You should constantly poll the buttons and when one is pressed:

1. Check byte 0 of your array.
2. If it's 0, store the floor here.
3. If it's not, check byte 1 (and so on)
4. If it's available (i.e. ==0) AND your value is different from byte 0, then store the floor here.

You should also poll the sensor value (to know where the car is) and:

1. If it's at a floor, check if it corresponds to the first value of your array
2. If so, stop the car and move every value of your array down by 1 (*array[0] = array [1]; array[1] = array [2]; array[2] = 0;*  assuming you have a history of only three values)

Note that your history could be much longer than the maxfloors constant. In that case, I would advise to do a *do {} while* to find the first available spot in the array.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found your problem, but I could be wrong. Your arrays and variables in your functions are outside of scope for your switch statement. At least, I think this is the problem. You should really make your code into minimal needed to display the error, otherwise it's really hard for us to help you. I had to read through the code twice to figure it out. I am pretty sure if you used pass by reference in your function parameters and declare the arrays in global or main(loop) scope your problem will be solved. Additionally, you could use a different return type for your functions besides void, like int, but you can only return one value from a function, so pass by reference is best suited for your purpose. Allow me to demonstrate the code with pass by reference. The way it is written, your functions do nothing because they return no values and do not modify any existing object either. This solution would need to be applied to all the functions that modify or create an object as well as the switch statement. In short, declare your arrays and variables in a larger scope and pass by reference to modify them. I hope this helps you.

```
int buttonstate[2];
int sensorstate[2];

void ReadButtons(&buttonstate)
{   

  for (int i=0;i<maxfloors;i++)
  {
    buttonstate[i] = digitalRead (carcall_buttons[i]);
  }
}

void ReadSensors(&sensorstate)
{   

  for (int i=0;i<maxfloors;i++)
  {
    sensorstate[i] = digitalRead (floor_sensors[i]);
  }
}
```